# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method

Tags: java, android

i tried to fix this
when i run i have a problem
i don't know how to fix this

this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 7525
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.myapplication.PegawaiAdaptar$OnClickListenerPegawai.onItemClikPegawai(long)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication.PegawaiAdaptar$PegawaiViewHolder$1.onClick(PegawaiAdaptar.java:85)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

this pegawai adaptar code in error:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long position = (long) itemView.getTag();
            listenerPegawai.onItemClikPegawai(position);
```

Comment: Seems like you have not initialised your listenerPegawai object. Can you add more of your code here ?

Comment: your listenerPegawai is null that's why is getting crashed.